# Binary Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Suppose instead of having labels already assigned to instances, I instead write a deterministic function from instances to labels that says,

"If instance A satisfies some condition, label it 0. Else, label it 1."

Then I run an ROC analysis on the resulting set of instances and labels.

Can someone tell me what, exactly, I have done? Am I merely testing the discriminative ability of my function as a classifier?

I'm a bit confused since in this case I am the one assigning labels. I am not assuming they are given and trying to learn a classifier, per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is pretty usual in machine learning. You are given an unknown stochatic process `f: IR^m -> IR^n` and further some kind of interesting information (denoted by labels) which is given as a function of the `n` outcomes, i.e. `g: IR^n -> {0,1}`.

Now you are only interested in these labels, and therefore you don't bother about predicting the original process `f` -- which is harder as it is multi-dimensional valued. Rather, you consider only the composed process

```
h: IR^m -> {0,1}, h = g o f
```

and try to perform a binary classification on this process.

In a way, this is done with about any binary classification data set. One can always construct -- sometimes artificially -- intermediate variables and then map these onto the binary result set (either through a known mapping as in your case or through a yet-to-infere mapping). Consider for example multilayer neural networks: the hidden layers can be considered as those intermediate variables. Similarly, for principal component regression, the input variables are first linearly transformed -- i.e. a deterministic mapping is applied -- and the resulting, hopefully easier stochastic process is inferred afterwards.

---

EDIT: Much depends on the labelling you apply. If it is a "natural" mapping from from intermediate varibles to {0,1}, i.e. one which directly classifies the quantity you're looking for and which is uniquely specified by the your setup, just go on. However, I have the impression that you're not totally sure about the quality of your mapping. In this case, I would refrain from influencing the machine learning method through your mapping and model directly the sought quantity ... maybe you can give a bit more details about your setup, then we can continue here.

Comment: This is a great answer and I will upvote it, there is just one thing I don't understand: in my case, how am I given an unknown stochastic process if I have written the deterministic function mapping instance to input? In other words, how is this process *unknown*? Wouldn't that only be the case if I had, to begin with, a set of instances and associated labels, and _hadn't_ generated them myself using this function?

Comment: @roccomay: what is unknown and stochastic is the primary process, the labelling itself is deterministic in your case. Now, a composition of an unknown stochastic process and a deterministic function is (in general) again an unknown stochastic process, but one which is hopefully easier to explain. I'll add some practical advice to my answer.